# AFNetworking duplicate content-length on 3g

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, 3g

We are using AFNetworking to handle URL requests back to the server.

For some reason we are seeing duplicate content-length headers only when working on 3G. When we are in WIFI there is no problem.

Anybody know why this would happen?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a known bug for AFNetworking, here is the link of one bug report https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/714, but is marked as duplicate, you should search for the duplicated bug and check if is fixed or if there is a workaround,

Answer (score 0):

Carriers have a tendency to change outgoing requests when connecting over cellular networks like 3G or EDGE (essentially, a benevolent man-in-the-middle attack). This is outside of the purview of AFNetworking, and quite possibly out of the hands of the URL Loading System (`NSURLConnection`) on which AFNetworking is based.